# May we use Yii flash messages on this scenario?

Tags: yii

I haven't seen this scenario covered here:
[Yii Framework: How to work with Flash Messages](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/#hh1).

So, after user registration, I wish to redirect the user to a thank you page where he/she could read more about what he/she should do, and what would happen next. It's *a nice amount* of information, so adding that message to an already existing page is not an option, because it would get to noisy. Making temporary displaying msg isn't an option neither, because it's a fair amount of text to be read.

On cases like this:

1. Should we still use **flash messages** and use a **conditional** so that what normally exists on the page stays hidden while display a success flash message ?

   OR
2. Should we simply **redirect** to a given thank you view (by creating the respective thankyou action?)

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a flash message.  But these are really for things like "Your account is now created".

If you want to include a good amount of information, I think it best to have a separate thankyou action/view that people are redirected to after the sign up process is complete.